# Invalid output for a custom print function when incorporating newline characters within a string for a kernel project

Tags: c++, gcc, output, kernel, newline

I'm in the process of working on a kernel program to handle printing capabilities of input for a custom OS. I'm following `Poncho's` 2nd YouTube Video series found [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxN4E629pPnJxCQCLy7E0SQY_zuumOVyZ), I'm currently on Video 4 in the series where he starts to add numerical types as inputs to the renderer's print function. Now, my code isn't exactly like his as I made some modifications.

*-Note- This won't compile directly as there is no `main` function. `_start` is being called or invoked by a `bootloader` that isn't shown here, I will however, add it to the bottom of this question.*

When I use the class's print function like this within my kernel:

```
#include "BasicRenderer.h"

extern "C" void _start(Framebuffer* framebuffer, PSF1_FONT** fonts) {
    BasicRenderer = renderer(framebuffer, fonts); 
    renderer.Print("This is some text");
    renderer.Print('\n');
    renderer.Print(uint64_t(123456789));
    renderer.Print('\n');
    renderer.Print(int64_t(-123456789));

    return;
}
```

And I run the kernel in `emu`. I'm getting the following output displayed:

```
This is some text
123456789
-123456789
```

The above is correct, however, when I try to incorporate the ability to parse a newline set of characters being either `\n` or `\0` within of a `const char*` that acts as a string as seen in the following example:

```
#include "BasicRenderer.h"

extern "C" void _start(Framebuffer* framebuffer, PSF1_FONT** fonts) {
    BasicRenderer = renderer(framebuffer, fonts); 
    renderer.Print("This is some text\n");
    renderer.Print(uint64_t(123456789));
    renderer.Print('\n');
    renderer.Print(int64_t(-123456789));

    return;
}
```

And now the displayed output is:

```
This is some text
 123456789
-123456789
```

Here, the output in the second line has a space preceding the numerical value to be displayed after the call to `Print()` that has a `\n` within its string. I'm not sure what is causing this in my code. Does it have to do with the `while` condition or how I'm incrementing and indexing into the character string within `BasicRenderer::Print(const char* str)`? Or is it coming from `BasicRender::PutChar(char c)`? Or is it within one of the `to_string()` functions?

---

Here is the relevant implementation code...

*BasicRenderer.cpp*

```
#include "BasicRenderer.h"

void BasicRenderer::Print(const char* str) {    
    char* chr = (char*)str;
    while(*chr != 0) {
        if ( (*chr == '\\') && ((*chr+1 == 'n') || (*chr+1 == '0')) ) {
            PutChar('\n');
            chr++;
            chr++;
        } else {
            PutChar(*chr);
            cursor_position_.x += 8;

            if (cursor_position_.x + 8 > framebuffer_->Width) {
                cursor_position_.x = 0;
                cursor_position_.y += 16;
            }
            chr++;
        }
    }
}

void BasicRenderer::Print(uint64_t val) {
    const char* str = to_string(val);
    Print(str);
}

void BasicRenderer::Print(int64_t val) {
    const char* str = to_string(val);
    Print(str);
}

void BasicRenderer::PutChar(char c) {       
    if (c == '\n' || c == '\0') {
        cursor_position_.x = 0;
        cursor_position_.y += 16;
    } else {        
        unsigned int* pixPtr = (unsigned int*)framebuffer_->BaseAddress;
        char* fontPtr = (char*)selected_font_->glyphBuffer + (c * selected_font_->psf1_Header->charsize);
        for (unsigned long y = cursor_position_.y; y < cursor_position_.y + 16; y++) {
            for (unsigned long x = cursor_position_.x; x < cursor_position_.x + 8; x++) {
                if ((*fontPtr & (0b10000000 >> (x - cursor_position_.x))) > 0) {
                    *(unsigned int*)(pixPtr + x + (y * framebuffer_->PixelsPerScanLine)) = font_color_;
                }
            }
            fontPtr++;
        }
    }
}
```

*cstr.cpp*

```
#include "cstr.h"

const char* to_string(uint64_t value) {
    static char output_uint_buffer[128];

    uint8_t size = 0;
    uint64_t sizeTest = value;
    while (sizeTest / 10 > 0) {
        sizeTest /= 10;
        size++;
    }

    uint8_t idx = 0;
    while (value / 10 > 0) {
        uint8_t remainder = value % 10;
        value /= 10;
        output_uint_buffer[size - idx] = remainder + '0';
        idx++;
    }
    uint8_t remainder = value % 10;
    output_uint_buffer[size-idx] = remainder + '0';
    output_uint_buffer[size + 1] = 0;
    return output_uint_buffer;
}

const char* to_string(int64_t value) {
    static char output_int_buffer[128];
    uint8_t isNegative = 0;

    if (value < 0) {
        isNegative = 1;
        value *= -1;
        output_int_buffer[0] = '-';
    }

    uint8_t size = 0;
    uint64_t sizeTest = value;
    while (sizeTest / 10 > 0) {
        sizeTest /= 10;
        size++;
    }

    uint8_t idx = 0;
    while (value / 10 > 0) {
        uint8_t remainder = value % 10;
        value /= 10;
        output_int_buffer[isNegative + size - idx] = remainder + '0';
        idx++;
    }
    uint8_t remainder = value % 10;
    output_int_buffer[isNegative + size - idx] = remainder + '0';
    output_int_buffer[isNegative + size + 1] = 0;
    return output_int_buffer;
}
```

And here is the rest of the declarations...

*BasicRender.h*

```
#pragma once

#include "cstr.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "framebuffer.h"
#include "SimpleFonts.h"

class BasicRenderer {
public:
    BasicRenderer(Framebuffer* framebuffer, PSF1_FONT** fonts) :
      framebuffer_{framebuffer}, 
      fonts_{fonts}, 
      cursor_position_({0,0}),
      selected_font_{fonts_[0]},
      font_color_{0xFFFFFFFF} 
    {}

    void Print(const char* str);        
    void Print(char c) { PutChar(c); }    
    void Print(uint64_t val);
    void Print(int64_t val);

private:
    void PutChar(char c);

    Framebuffer* framebuffer_;
    Point cursor_position_;
    PSF1_FONT** fonts_;
    PSF1_FONT* selected_font_;
    unsigned int font_color_;
};
```

*cstr.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>

const char* to_string(uint64_t value);
const char* to_string(int64_t value);
```

*math.h*

```
#pragma once

struct Point {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
};
```

*Framebuffer.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <stddef.h>

struct Framebuffer {
    void* BaseAddress;
    size_t BufferSize;
    unsigned int Width;
    unsigned int Height;
    unsigned int PixelsPerScanLine;
};
```

*SimpleFonts.h*

```
#pragma once

struct PSF1_HEADER {
    unsigned char magic[2];
    unsigned char mode;
    unsigned char charsize;
};

struct PSF1_FONT {
    PSF1_HEADER* psf1_Header;
    void* glyphBuffer;
};
```

---

Here is the `bootloader` application that invokes the above `kernel`.

*main.c*

```
#include <efi.h>    
#include <efilib.h>    
#include <elf.h>   

#define PSF1_MAGIC0 0x36    
#define PSF1_MAGIC1 0x04    

typedef unsigned long long size_t;    

typedef struct {    
    unsigned char magic[2];    
    unsigned char mode;    
    unsigned char charsize;    
} PSF1_HEADER;    

typedef struct {    
    PSF1_HEADER* psf1_Header;    
    void* glyphBuffer;    
} PSF1_FONT;    

typedef struct {    
    void* BaseAddress;    
    size_t BufferSize;    
    unsigned int Width;    
    unsigned int Height;
    unsigned int PixelsPerScanLine;    
} Framebuffer; Framebuffer framebuffer;

Framebuffer* InitializeGOP() {    
    EFI_GUID gopGuid = EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL_GUID; 
    EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL* gop;    
    EFI_STATUS status;    
    status = uefi_call_wrapper(BS->LocateProtocol, 3, &gopGuid, NULL, (void**)&gop);    
    if (EFI_ERROR(status)) {    
        Print(L"Unable to locate GOP\n\r");    
        return NULL;    
    } else {    
        Print(L"GOP located\n\r");
    }   

    framebuffer.BaseAddress = (void*)gop->Mode->FrameBufferBase;
    framebuffer.BufferSize = gop->Mode->FrameBufferSize;    
    framebuffer.Width = gop->Mode->Info->HorizontalResolution;    
    framebuffer.Height = gop->Mode->Info->VerticalResolution;    
    framebuffer.PixelsPerScanLine = gop->Mode->Info->PixelsPerScanLine;    

    return &framebuffer;    
}    

EFI_FILE* LoadFile(EFI_FILE* Directory, CHAR16* Path, EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* SystemTable) {    
    EFI_FILE* LoadedFile;    
    EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL* LoadedImage;    
    SystemTable->BootServices->HandleProtocol(ImageHandle, &gEfiLoadedImageProtocolGuid, (void**)&LoadedImage);    
    EFI_SIMPLE_FILE_SYSTEM_PROTOCOL* FileSystem;    
    SystemTable->BootServices->HandleProtocol(LoadedImage->DeviceHandle, &gEfiSimpleFileSystemProtocolGuid, (void**)&FileSystem);    

    if (Directory == NULL) {    
        FileSystem->OpenVolume(FileSystem, &Directory);    
    }   

    EFI_STATUS s = Directory->Open(Directory, &LoadedFile, Path, EFI_FILE_MODE_READ, EFI_FILE_READ_ONLY);    
    if (s != EFI_SUCCESS) {    
        return NULL;    
    }    
    return LoadedFile;    
}    

PSF1_FONT* LoadPSF1Font(EFI_FILE* Directory, CHAR16* Path, EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* SystemTable) {    
    EFI_FILE* font = LoadFile(Directory, Path, ImageHandle, SystemTable);    
    if (font == NULL) return NULL;  

    PSF1_HEADER* fontHeader;    
    SystemTable->BootServices->AllocatePool(EfiLoaderData, sizeof(PSF1_HEADER), (void**)&fontHeader);    
    UINTN size = sizeof(PSF1_HEADER);    
    font->Read(font, &size, fontHeader);    
    if (fontHeader->magic[0] != PSF1_MAGIC0 || fontHeader->magic[1] != PSF1_MAGIC1) return NULL;    

    UINTN glyphBufferSize = fontHeader->charsize * 256;    
    if (fontHeader->mode == 1) { // 512 glyph mode    
        glyphBufferSize *= 2;    
    }

    void* glyphBuffer;    
    font->SetPosition(font, sizeof(PSF1_HEADER));    
    SystemTable->BootServices->AllocatePool(EfiLoaderData, glyphBufferSize, (void**)&glyphBuffer);    
    font->Read(font, &glyphBufferSize, glyphBuffer);    
    PSF1_FONT* finishedFont;    
    SystemTable->BootServices->AllocatePool(EfiLoaderData, sizeof(PSF1_FONT), (void**)&finishedFont);    
    finishedFont->psf1_Header = fontHeader;    
    finishedFont->glyphBuffer = glyphBuffer;    
    return finishedFont;    
}    

int memcmp(const void* aptr, const void* bptr, size_t n) {    
    const unsigned char* a = aptr, *b = bptr;    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {    
        if (a[i] < b[i]) return -1;    
        else if(a[i] > b[i]) return 1;    
    }    
    return 0;    
}    

EFI_STATUS efi_main (EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable) {    
    InitializeLib(ImageHandle, SystemTable);    
    Print(L"Hello World!\n\r");    
    EFI_FILE* Kernel = LoadFile(NULL, L"kernel.elf", ImageHandle, SystemTable);    
    if ( Kernel == NULL) {    
        Print(L"Could not load kernel \n\r");    
    } else {    
        Print(L"Kernel Loaded Successfully \n\r"); 
    }

    Elf64_Ehdr header; 
    {  
        UINTN FileInfoSize;    
        EFI_FILE_INFO* FileInfo;    
        Kernel->GetInfo(Kernel, &gEfiFileInfoGuid, &FileInfoSize, NULL);    
        SystemTable->BootServices->AllocatePool(EfiLoaderData, FileInfoSize, (void**)&FileInfo);    
        Kernel->GetInfo(Kernel, &gEfiFileInfoGuid, &FileInfoSize, (void**)&FileInfo);    
        UINTN size = sizeof(header);    
        Kernel->Read(Kernel, &size, &header);   
    }    

    if (    
        memcmp(&header.e_ident[EI_MAG0], ELFMAG, SELFMAG) != 0 ||    
        header.e_ident[EI_CLASS] != ELFCLASS64 ||    
        header.e_ident[EI_DATA] != ELFDATA2LSB ||    
        header.e_type != ET_EXEC ||    
        header.e_machine != EM_X86_64 ||    
        header.e_version != EV_CURRENT    
    ) {    
        Print(L"kernel format is bad\r\n");    
    } else {    
        Print(L"kernel header successfully verified\r\n");    
    }    

    Elf64_Phdr* phdrs;    
    {    
        Kernel->SetPosition(Kernel, header.e_phoff);    
        UINTN size = header.e_phnum * header.e_phentsize;    
        SystemTable->BootServices->AllocatePool(EfiLoaderData, size, (void**)&phdrs);    
        Kernel->Read(Kernel, &size, phdrs);    
    }

    for (    
        Elf64_Phdr* phdr = phdrs;    
        (char*)phdr < (char*)phdrs + header.e_phnum * header.e_phentsize;    
        phdr = (Elf64_Phdr*)((char*)phdr + header.e_phentsize)      
    ) {    
        switch(phdr->p_type) {    
            case PT_LOAD: {    
                int pages = (phdr->p_memsz + 0x1000 - 1) / 0x1000;    
                Elf64_Addr segment = phdr->p_paddr;    
                SystemTable->BootServices->AllocatePages(AllocateAddress, EfiLoaderData, pages, &segment);    
                Kernel->SetPosition(Kernel, phdr->p_offset);    
                UINTN size = phdr->p_filesz;    
                Kernel->Read(Kernel, &size, (void*)segment);    
                break;    
            }    
        }    
    }   

    Print(L"Kernel Loaded\n\r");

    void (*KernelStart)(Framebuffer*, PSF1_FONT**) = ((__attribute__((sysv_abi)) void(*)(Framebuffer*, PSF1_FONT**) ) header.e_entry);    

    PSF1_FONT* newFont = LoadPSF1Font(NULL, L"zap-light16.psf", ImageHandle, SystemTable);    
    if (newFont == NULL) {    
        Print(L"Font is not valid or is not found\n\r");    
    } else {    
        Print(L"Font found, char size = %d\n\r", newFont->psf1_Header->charsize);    
    }    

    PSF1_FONT* newFontExt = LoadPSF1Font(NULL, L"zap-ext-light16.psf", ImageHandle, SystemTable);    
    if (newFont == NULL) {
        Print(L"Font is not valid or is not found\n\r");
    } else {
        Print(L"Font found, char size = %d\n\r", newFont->psf1_Header->charsize);
    }
    PSF1_FONT* fonts[] = {newFont, newFontExt};
    Framebuffer* newBuffer = InitializeGOP();

    Print(L"Base: 0x%x\n\rSize: 0x%x\n\rWidth: %d\n\rHeight: %d\n\rPixelsPerScanline: %d\n\r",
    newBuffer->BaseAddress, 
    newBuffer->BufferSize, 
    newBuffer->Width,
    newBuffer->Height, 
    newBuffer->PixelsPerScanLine);
    KernelStart(newBuffer, fonts);

    return EFI_SUCCESS; // Exit the UEFI application    
}
```

Comment: There's some inconsistency here. If you `PutChar` a newline, you update `cursor_position_` otherwise you don't change it, and the caller has to update it. The base `Print` could be simpler if you made `PutChar` always update the positions (which could also make variable width fonts simpler to add if you go that route).

Comment: Also note that `*chr+1` is parsed as `(*chr)+1`, which since you already know that `*chr == '\\'` will mean your second condition is always false.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I understand what you're saying about the `PutChar` function. Right now, I'm just following along with the video series... I've made a few modifications to his code but it's relatively the same...

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm ... I may eventually remove the `print` from the renderer itself... and have them as free functions, move the font into its own class, and just have the renderer with its framebuffer as a backend, and that the print functions will use a hidden buffer that is automatically handled that will allow control of the cursor position... also I may end up incorporating the font to be change, and the renderer - framebuffer will update accordingly. This way the print functions will use the `putchar` function and don't need to know about the framebuffer or the font...

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm ... Only the `putchar` function really needs to know about the framebuffer, cursor position, and font sizes to work properly... I'm actually in the process of taking all of his print functions for each type and I'm `templating` them...

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm This is my first time or attempt at writing `kernel` type code for a custom operating system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if ( (*chr == '\\') && ((*chr+1 == 'n') || (*chr+1 == '0')) ) {
    PutChar('\n');
    chr++;
    chr++;
}
...
```

You should not be parsing out `\n` since this will be present in the string as a linefeed character.  What you want instead is:

```
if (*chr == '\n') {
    PutChar('\n');
    chr++;
}
...
```

Comment: Okay, that does make sense... but would it be the same for `\0` if that is found in the string to be printed?

Comment: Yeah I'm new to this `kernel` - `os` type programming, but going through series like these is helping me to bridge the gap between how the Architecture(ISA - Assembler) communicates with an arbitrary Operating System and how that Operating System interacts with programs or applications within that system. This will give me a better understanding of the internal mechanics of how a given higher level language such as C/C++ and their Compilers are designed and why they are designed in the way that they are...

Comment: Now, since the bootloader is written in C that invokes this kernel and the kernel itself is written and compiled in C++. The C++ language and its compiler is interpreting or handling the newline `\n` character for me, so as you stated in your answer, I don't have to do this manually because its written in C/C++ and not Assembly!